# Return back to MainActivity after pressing back button from MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Hi i am newbiew to android i am using back button code in my first activity that is from MainActivity and the app goes to background or exits from the app but when i return back to the app instead of entering the first activity its going to some other page(activity) of the app. I have used the following code

```
    @Override
         public void onBackPressed() 
         {
          //super.onBackPressed();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                                                     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//***Change Here***
                        // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                       //  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                       //  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                         startActivity(intent);
                         //moveTaskToBack(true);

                           finish();
                        System.exit(0);




         }
```

I have tried using moveTaskToBack(true) code but it does not refresh the activity, it gives back the first page as such but the login preference does not change. Please someone help me in this task

Comment: Not doing anything will give you that functionality since it's the default behavior. Back press finishes the activity and when there are no more activities to go back to, you simply leave the app. Once you start it again, the first activity is started.

Comment: not doing anything means not writing the onBackPressed() method code in the activity will save problem hey

Comment: What? Yes, delete the whole `onBackPressed`.

Comment: i cannot do so because while pressing button back it also simultaneously changes the status of user to zero when pressed back and again changes status to one when app is pressed again

Comment: why the hell -1 mark 37 times it has been viewed and no one can solve or correct it but knows to give a -1 mark

Answer (score 0):

Just add this lines of code into your launcher activity's oncreate() method

```
if (!isTaskRoot()
                && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                && getIntent().getAction() != null
                && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

            finish();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: it does not help either